# Question about proving infinite union of sequence of countable sets is countable.

Tags: analysis

Let {$E_n$} , $n$=1,2,3... be a sequence of countable sets, and then

$S$ = $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $E_n$

The proof in my book says

Let every $E_n$ be arranged in a sequence {$x_{nk}$} $k$=1,2,3....

and consider the infinite array

$x_{11}\ x_{12}\ x_{13}\ x_{14}$

$x_{21}\ x_{22}\ x_{23}\ x_{24}$

.....

in which the elments of $E_n $ form the nth row.

Then $x_{11} ;x_{21} x_{12}; x_{31}x_{22}x_{13} $...becomes a sequence, which I understood.

But what I want to know is that after that,

```
1. Why there exists a subset T of the set of all positive integers s.t S~T
 It seems like the sequence is countable... right?
2. How can I set T?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispensing with the $x$ and writing $(n,m)$ for $x_{nm}$, we can map $(n,m)$ to $2^n \times 3^m$. This is a bijection between $\mathbb N^2$ and a proper subset of $\mathbb N$. For example $(3,5)$ maps to $2^3 \times 3^5 = 8 \times 81 = 648$. And by unique factorization, the mapping is reversible. If I give you $648$ you can factor it and get back $(3,5)$.

This shows that you can match up each element of your array to some positive integer and have integers left over. For example $7$ does not get hit by our mapping.

Another way to think of this informally is that if you had to carry a pair of positive integers in your bag but your bag can only fit one integer at a time, you can take two integers, combine them into one integer via the $2^n \times 3^m$ trick, and put that single integer in the bag. Later we take the integer out of the bag, factor it, and recover our original two integers. Magic!

Since an infinite subset of a countably infinite set must be countably infinite, your array is countably infinite.

Your set $T$ is just the set of all products $2^n \times 3^m$ as $n$ and $m$ range over the positive integers.

Comment: So the map exists, my first question is solved?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

One point which no one has brought out yet is that this theorem ("a countable union of countable sets is countable") requires the axiom of choice.  This is a subtle point that's worth mentioning, but you might want to skip it if this is the first time you have seen this.

You are given a sequence $\langle E_n | n \textrm{ is a positive integer} \rangle$ where each $E_n$ is countable.  That means that for each positive integer $n$, there exists a function $f$ mapping $\lbrace 1, 2, \dots \rbrace $ onto $E_n$.  (I'm assuming here that each $E_n$ is non-empty.  If any $E_n$ is actually empty, then there's no such corresponding $f$, but it's easy to see that handling that situation doesn't present any difficulty in the proof.)

However, for each $n$, there may be *many* corresponding functions $f$ with the required property.  In general, you need the axiom of choice to be able to choose a particular counting for each $E_n$ — in other words, to say that there is a function $F$ with domain $\lbrace 1, 2, \dots \rbrace $ such that for each positive integer $n$, $F(n)$ is itself a function mapping $\lbrace 1, 2, \dots \rbrace $ onto $E_n$.

Once we have $F$, we can proceed as others have explained to define a function $g$ with domain $\lbrace 1, 2, \dots \rbrace $ by stitching all the functions $F(n)$ together.  Then $g$ maps $\lbrace 1, 2, \dots \rbrace $ onto $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$.

In fact, there are models of set theory (ZF) in which the axiom of choice fails in such a way that the set of real numbers is a countable union of countable sets (even though the set of real numbers is uncountable).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than starting counting from $1$, we can start the index from $0$.

After which, we can use Cantor pairing function.

[Wikipedia page about Cantor pairing function with cool picture there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function)